# Jquery .load() not firing consitently

Tags: jquery, load

I have the following code:

```
$('#result').load('http://www.mystie.com/speicificpage h2:contains(unique1)');
```

It works great BUT sometimes doesn't work at all.. and I have no freaking idea why..

I tried to use the ajax  not cache but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What error are you getting when it "doesn't work at all"?

Comment: why do you have a css selector at the end ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Firebug or Chrome's dev tools to look for a network response?

Comment: Make sure you are not asking for content from a different domain

Comment: @VeXii the selector is valid. See http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Comment: no erros, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. If I clear ALL browser data, ie reset safari ti works. then it stops working.

Comment: I am getting this error "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." I don't get it since it's on the same server, but different folders.. could that be it?

Answer (score 1):

And chance that it does not work if people are visiting your page as http://mystie.com/ instead of http://www.mystie.com/? In that case the request might be considered as "cross domain". Changing it to:

```
$('#result').load('/speicificpage h2:contains(unique1)');
```

might help.

(Oh, and is the `h2:contains(unique1)` really part of the url? Looks more like part of a jQuery CSS-selector to me. Just wondering.)

Comment: The selector after the URL tells jQuery to find and put only the matched elements into the container.

Comment: Ah, I never noticed this feature. Thanks for enlighen me about that!

Comment: the content is coming from the same server.